# What is the best way to set the attributes of a class at object creation time in Python?

Tags: python, class, attributes

When I define a class, I often want to set a collection of attributes for that class upon object creation. Until now, I have done so by passing the attributes as arguments to the **init** method. However, I have been unhappy with the repetitive nature of such code:

```
class Repository(OrderedDict,UserOwnedObject,Describable):
  def __init__(self,user,name,gitOriginURI=None,gitCommitHash=None,temporary=False,sourceDir=None):
    self.name = name
    self.gitOriginURI = gitOriginURI
    self.gitCommitHash = gitCommitHash
    self.temporary = temporary
    self.sourceDir = sourceDir
    ...
```

In this example, I have to type `name` three times, `gitOriginURI` three times, `gitCommitHash` three times, `temporary` three times, and `sourceDir` three times. Just to set these attributes. This is extremely boring code to write.

I've considered changing classes like this to be along the lines of:

```
class Foo():
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = None
    self.b = None
    self.c = None
```

And initializing their objects like:

```
f = Foo()
f.a = whatever
f.b = something_else
f.c = cheese
```

But from a documentation standpoint, this seems worse, because the user of the class then needs to know which attributes need to be set, rather than simply looking at the autogenerated `help()` string for the class's initializer.

Are there any better ways to do this?

One thing that I think might be an interesting solution, would be if there was a `store_args_to_self()` method which would store every argument passed to init as an attribute to self. Does such a method exist?

One thing that makes me pessimistic about this quest for a better way, is that looking at the source code for the `date` object in cPython's source, for example, I see this same repetitive code:

```
def __new__(cls, year, month=None, day=None):
    ...
    self._year = year
    self._month = month
    self._day = day
```

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/datetime.py#L705

And urwid, though slightly obfuscated by the use of setters, also has such "take an argument and set it as an attribute to self" hot-potato code:

```
def __init__(self, caption=u"", edit_text=u"", multiline=False,
        align=LEFT, wrap=SPACE, allow_tab=False,
        edit_pos=None, layout=None, mask=None):
    ...

    self.__super.__init__("", align, wrap, layout)
    self.multiline = multiline
    self.allow_tab = allow_tab
    self._edit_pos = 0
    self.set_caption(caption)
    self.set_edit_text(edit_text)
    if edit_pos is None:
        edit_pos = len(edit_text)
    self.set_edit_pos(edit_pos)
    self.set_mask(mask)
```

https://github.com/urwid/urwid/blob/master/urwid/widget.py#L1158

Comment: I don't get what the problem is with writing the variable name three times. The main advantage is that it is in the documentation of the `__init__`. So if you use an IDE, it will hint the names later. Some work for now, much benefit later. Furthermore you do not perse immediately assign to attributes: it is possible that you first want to validate the values, then do some processing, and then set the attribute to the result of that processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`dataclasses` project](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dataclasses) to have it take care of generating the `__init__` method for you; it'll also take care of a representation, hashing and equality testing (and optionally, rich comparisons and immutability):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional

@dataclass
class Repository(OrderedDict, UserOwnedObject, Describable):
    name: str
    gitOriginURI: Optional[str] = None
    gitCommitHash: Optional[str] = None
    temporary: bool = False
    sourceDir: Optional[str] = None
```

`dataclasses` were defined in [PEP 557 - *Data Classes*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/), which has been accepted for inclusion in Python 3.7. The library will work on Python 3.6 and up (as it relies on the new variable annotation syntax introduced in 3.6).

The project was inspired by the [`attrs` project](http://attrs.org), which offers some more flexibility and options still, as well as compatibility with Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 and up.

Comment: This looks like just what I want. It is too bad that it is an external lib, but I'm OK with that for my current project. Do you know if it is possible to make a dataclass without specifying the types of the attributes?

Comment: @timthelion: no, `dataclasses` specifically looks for class variables defined with [variable annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/). Use `attrs` if this doesn't fit your project. The library will be part of Python 3.7 onwards however.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *could* do this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

foo = Foo(a=1, b='two', c='iii')
print(foo.a, foo.b, foo.c)
```

**output**

```
1 two iii
```

But if you do, it's probably a Good Idea to check that the keys in `kwargs` are sane before dumping them into your instances `__dict__`. ;)

Here's a slightly fancier example that does a little bit of checking of the passed-in args.

```
class Foo:
    attrs = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    ''' Some stuff about a, b, & c '''
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        valid = {key: kwargs.get(key) for key in self.attrs}
        self.__dict__.update(valid)

    def __repr__(self):
        args = ', '.join(['{}={}'.format(key, getattr(self, key)) for key in self.attrs])
        return 'Foo({})'.format(args)

foo = Foo(a=1, c='iii', d='four')
print(foo)
```

**output**

```
Foo(a=1, b=None, c=iii)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While I could do this, it would have the same problem as the second method which I gave. There is no documentation of the appropriate attributes in the class's `help()` string.

Comment: @timthelion Understood. You can improve this approach by supplying a list of permitted attributes, as shown in my 2nd example. And you could make it more robust by adding some type checking. But you still need to write an appropriate docstring. However, Martijn's suggestion _is_ superior, and as he mentions, `dataclasses` will become part of the standard library in Python 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

For Python 2.7 my solution is to inherit from namedtuple and use namedtuple itself as only argument to init. To avoid overloading new every time we can use decorator. The advantage is that we have explicit **init** signature w/o *args, **kwargs and, so, nice IDE suggestions

```
def nt_child(c):
    def __new__(cls, p): return super(c, cls).__new__(cls, *p)
    c.__new__ = staticmethod(__new__)
    return c

ClassA_P = namedtuple('ClassA_P', 'a, b, foo, bar')

@nt_child
class ClassA(ClassA_P):
    def __init__(self, p):
        super(ClassA, self).__init__(*p)
        self.something_more = sum(p)

a = ClassA(ClassA_P(1,2,3,4)) # a = ClassA(ClassA_P( <== suggestion a, b, foo, bar
print a.something_more # print a. <== suggesion a, b, foo, bar, something_more
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll just leave another one recipe here. `attrs` is useful, but have cons, main of which is lack of IDE suggestions for class `__init__`.

Also it's fun to have initialization chains, where we use instance of parent class as first arg for `__init__` instead of providing all it's attrs one by one.

So I propose the simple decorator. It analyses `__init__` signature and automatically adds class attributes, based on it (so approach is opposite to attrs's one). This gave us nice IDE suggestions for `__init__` (but lack of suggestions on attributes itself).

Usage:

```
@data_class
class A:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar): pass

@data_class
class B(A):
    # noinspection PyMissingConstructor
    def __init__(self, a, red, fox):
        self.red_plus_fox = red + fox
        # do not call parent constructor, decorator will do it for you

a = A(1, 2)
print a.__attrs__ # {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}

b = B(a, 3, 4) # {'fox': 4, 'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'red': 3, 'red_plus_fox': 7}
print b.__attrs__
```

Source:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def make_call_dict(f, is_class_method, *args, **kwargs):
    vnames = f.__code__.co_varnames[int(is_class_method):f.__code__.co_argcount]
    defs = f.__defaults__ or []

    d = OrderedDict(zip(vnames, [None] * len(vnames)))
    d.update({vn: d for vn, d in zip(vnames[-len(defs):], defs)})
    d.update(kwargs)
    d.update({vn: v for vn, v in zip(vnames, args)})
    return d

def data_class(cls):
    inherited = hasattr(cls, '_fields')
    if not inherited: setattr(cls, '_fields', None)
    __init__old__ = cls.__init__

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        d = make_call_dict(__init__old__, True, *args, **kwargs)

        if inherited:
            # tricky call of parent __init__
            O = cls.__bases__[0]  # put parent dataclass first in inheritance list
            o = d.values()[0]  # first arg in my __init__ is parent class object
            d = OrderedDict(d.items()[1:])
            isg = o._fields[O]  # parent __init__ signature, [0] shows is he expect data object as first arg
            O.__init__(self, *(([o] if isg[0] else []) + [getattr(o, f) for f in isg[1:]]))
        else:
            self._fields = {}

        self.__dict__.update(d)

        self._fields.update({cls: [inherited] + d.keys()})

        __init__old__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    cls.__attrs__ = property(lambda self: {k: v for k, v in self.__dict__.items()
                                           if not k.startswith('_')})
    cls.__init__ = __init__
    return cls
```